# how to separate channels of a topic of the type sensor_msgs/Image

Tags: ros, messages, sensor, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I'm new to ROS and struggling with understanding it so I would really appreciate your help. I have a node which publishes /ladybug_image with type sensor_msgs/Image but I need to extract the green channel of this topic. I looked at the ros documentation about sensor_msgs/Image. To me it sounds the uint8[] data contains the image data but I don't get how can I refer to each channel explicitly. Could you please help me how can I do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202728/how-to-separate-channels-of-a-topic-of-the-type-sensor_msgs/image/) by [z.bagheri63](https://answers.ros.org/users/5896/z.bagheri63/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-02-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,

the uint8[] data is the raw image data. inorder to have individual channel you need to know the image data is structured or unstructured. it means the it is RGB[pix1] RGB[pix2]....... or R[pix1] R[pix2].........G[pix1] G[pix2].........B[pix1] B[pix2].......... once u know which type it is using a incremental loop  (for loop) you can extract whatever you want. i can give you one eg i used for reconstruction of image in the subscriber node.

```
for(int i=(w-1);i>=0;i--)
{
    for(int j=(h-1);j>=0;j--)
    { 
        *(image(i,j)) = *(&img->data[count]);
        count++;
        *(image(i,j)+1) = *(&img->data[count]);
        count++;
        *(image(i,j)+2) = *(&img->data[count]);
        count++;
    }
}
```

here img is sensor_msgs::Image.
please tell me if its not clear.

---

Originally posted by [Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20363/robot/) with karma: 180 on 2015-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could use [cv_bridge](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge) to convert the incoming `sensor_msgs/Image` into an OpenCV datatype. This allows you to use OpenCV functions to perform operations such as accessing channels. As an additional note, you can look at the string contained in the `encoding` field of the `sensor_msgs/Image` to determine what format the image is expressed in.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2015-02-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1